# DrRacket tutorial help using multiple images in using animate

Tags: racket

New to programming but i'm following a tutorial from Racket and Im trying to have a rocket land on a landing base.  Got the rocket to work but I wanted to add some more objects like a landing base. Here is what I have:

```
; constants
(define width 100)
(define height 100)
(define background "sky blue")
(define mtscn (empty-scene width height background))
(define rocket.)
(define rocket-center-to-bottom
  (- height (/ (image-height rocket) 2)))
(define base.)
(define base-center-to-bottom
  (- height (/ (image-height rocket) 2)))

  ; functions
  (define (create-rocket-scene.v6 h)
    (cond
    [(<= h rocket-center-to-bottom)
  (place-image rocket 50 h mtscn)]
    [(> h rocket-center-to-bottom)
     (place-image rocket 50 rocket-center-to-bottom mtscn)]
    [(<= h base-center-to-bottom)
   (place-image base 50 h mtscn)]
    [(> h base-center-to-bottom)
     (place-image base 50 base-center-to-bottom mtscn)]))


(animate create-rocket-scene.v6)
```

basically copied and paste the rocket code then renamed rocket to base then made a base image. It says its working but the base doesn't show up. I want the base image to stay at the bottom while the rocket comes from the top to the bottom where the base is. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the where the problem is:

```
(cond
    [(<= h rocket-center-to-bottom) (place-image rocket 50 h mtscn)]
    [(> h rocket-center-to-bottom)  (place-image rocket 50 rocket-center-to-bottom mtscn)]
    [(<= h base-center-to-bottom)   (place-image base 50 h mtscn)]
    [(> h base-center-to-bottom)    (place-image base 50 base-center-to-bottom mtscn)])
```

A `cond`-expression finds the first "question" that is true,
and uses the "answer" that goes with it.

If `(<= h rocket-center-to-bottom)` is true, then the first clause is used, and 
`(place-image rocket 50 h mtscn)` is used. This means that the third clause where you use `base` is never reached.

Instead you need to draw both the mountain scene and the base to the same picture:

```
(place-image base 50 h 
  (place-image rocket 50 h mtscn))
```

This places the rocket on top of the mountain scene, and on top of that the base.

That is, you need only two clauses in the `cond`:

```
(cond
    [(<= h rocket-center-to-bottom)     (place-image base 50 h 
                                          (place-image rocket 50 h mtscn))]
    [(> h rocket-center-to-bottom)      ...draw-both-here...])
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Here's what i got to work.                                                           (cond
        [(<= h rocket-center-to-bottom)
         (place-image base 50 97
                      (place-image rocket 50 h mtscn))]
        [(> h rocket-center-to-bottom)
         (place-image base 50 97
                      (place-image rocket 50 rocket-center-to-bottom mtscn))]))

Comment: @shaol Great to hear it worked. Remember to upvote and/or accept the answer (use the green check mark) if you are satisfied with the answer.